# What causes the large delay in reporting the final results of Arizona, Michigan and New Hampshire?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

Well after the other states declared their results, Google, [BBC](http://www.bbc.com/news/election/us2016/results) and [the New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/elections/results/) show these three states as not yet declared. Indeed, it looks like all states have finished counting votes (NYT and BBC show 100% reporting for these states). So, why the delay in updating? Have they skipped these states since Trump has already won enough states?

Similarly, these sites still show some Senate and House seats as not committed yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All these 3 sites, Google, BBC and the New York Times, uses data from Associated Press as stated on the respective websites. So, though they might seem like they are from 3 different sources, they are *basically* the same.

---

I can't seem to find the exact reason why the race wasn't called. But for Arizona, it might be due to outstanding early and provisional ballots still being counted as seen below in [this article](http://www.azcentral.com/story/news/politics/elections/2016/11/08/arizona-election-results-2016-voting-updates/93289328/):

> There are more than 600,000 votes still to be processed statewide, per an Arizona Republic analysis of state and county data.  That number could grow as more counties report their number of early and provisional ballots outstanding.
>
> Maricopa County will have a small update to vote totals Wednesday, but for the most part will be processing early ballots all day, Bartholomew said. County officials will begin tabulating early ballots at 9 am on Thursday, she said.

---

Another reason that AP has already called's that Trump has already won, so there won't be any rush to call it. As seen in [this live blog](http://hotair.com/archives/2016/11/08/presidential-race-live-blog-fl-nc-pa-nh-make-or-break/) which also uses data from AP, AP's last projection is Trump winning the presidency and it hasn't called any states after that.

---

Just a note, CNN has already called Arizona for Trump and New Hampshire for Clinton, leaving only Michigan.