# Where are the missing 16 delegates in the US presidential election?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, electoral-college

Question 1. The total number of delegates for the US presidential election is 538, so that the majority is at 270. Now, Trump got 290 delegates while Clinton has 232: this is a total of 522. Where are the missing 16?

Question 2. Note that if these 16 all favor Clinton, she would reach 248 and the gap with Trump would reduce to 42. This would mean that if 22 delegates flip on her side, the result of the election is changed. I heard that 7 delegates are thinking of changing side: is it realistic to think that 22 could do so?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because (1) it's too broad (2 parts); (2) first part is a duplicate of an older question; (3) second part has no objective answer that isn't an opinion.

Comment: Both questions are duplicates:  note that there are 16 electoral votes in Michigan; [second](http://politics.stackexchange.com/q/13390/4666).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes the large delay in reporting the final results of Arizona, Michigan and New Hampshire?](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13173/what-causes-the-large-delay-in-reporting-the-final-results-of-arizona-michigan)

Answer (score 2):

#### Question 1:

The 16 missing "delegates", or electors, are from the state of Michigan. Trump is [currently leading by 0.3%](http://www.nytimes.com/elections/results/michigan) with 100% of precincts reporting.

AP hasn't called the state for Trump as the margin is too slim.

#### Question 2:

Since Trump is currently leading, Clinton isn't likely to win the state unless there's a recount.

Regarding faithless electors, asking more than 10 electors not to vote according to their state's results is unprecedented. Check out [What is the maximum count of faithless electors Clinton can possibly get in 2016?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13278/what-is-the-maximum-count-of-faithless-electors-can-clinton-possibly-get-in-2016/13280#13280).